# What is the difference between feedback and response?

Tags: difference, american-english

What is the difference between **feedback** and **responses** ?

Answer (score 1):

**Response** is an answer or reply to anything (doesn't necessarily have to be a question), so you can think of it as a more generic term, for example:

- I sent him a message this morning, but still haven't received his response.
- She smiled in response to to my greeting.

**Feedback** is a critical assessment on a specific given info, for example:

- Customer feedback is important for improving a product.

The response given by the customer was specifically about the product, therefore made this response a feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put:

Response is just a stimulant given on behalf of the question. You can ask me a question such as what is my name. Even though I say 'no,' it counts as a response.

Feedback:

Includes something valuable and contributing towards result/question.

Comment: A note on formulating answers with this software. One has to hit the spacebar twice to separate short lines from each other. With only one hit on the spacebar, two short sentences or lines of text end up squished on the same line. You can check the preview to see exactly what works. That is how I learned. I am also fairly new on Stack Exchange.